# chown all files based on file name pattern in current directory

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, find, filenames

I'm trying to chown all files whose filenames begin with `ChownFileNames`. I've used this command, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 |grep 'ChownFileNames*' -exec chown hadoop:hadoop -- {} . \;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
chown hadoop:hadoop ChownFileNames*
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work for what you need:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname 'ChownFileNames*' -exec chown hadoop:hadoop -- {} . \;
```

Comment: it's much better to use `\+` instead of `\;` in such cases. It will start one process per multiple files insted of one process per file, therefore the job will be done much faster on large amount of files.

Comment: If you're doing this for a directory, lose the dot (`.`) after `{}`, add recursive `-R`, and add `-type` option to `find`: `find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -iname 'ChownFileNames*' -exec chown -R hadoop:hadoop -- {} \;`.   To `find` in current as well as all sub folders, lose `-maxdepth 1`.

Answer (score 5):

The `|` (“pipe”) symbol means to pass the output of the command on the left to the command on the right. The command `find . -maxdepth 1` lists the files in the current directory (plus `.` itself). The command `grep 'ChownFileNames*' -exec chown hadoop:hadoop -- {} . \;` doesn't make any sense: you're passing `find` options to the `grep` command.

`find` itself has a way to match file names, the `-name` predicate. It takes a shell wildcard pattern as argument.

You could use `grep` to filter the list, but you'd have to provide a valid command line to `grep`. To retain only file names matching the shell pattern `ChownFileNames*`, you would need to use the regular expression `/ChownFileNames[^/]$`. Then you would have to parse the output of `grep` to transform the list of matching names into command line arguments. Assuming that you're running Linux and the file names do not contain any newlines, you could use `xargs`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 |
grep '/ChownFileNames[^/]*$' |
xargs -d '\n' chown hadoop:hadoop
```

It is a lot simpler and more robust to use `find`'s `-exec` action. Note that you can use `-exec … {} +` to run the command for a batch of files at once instead of once per file. You can also make `find` list the current directory.

```
find . maxdepth 1 \( -name . -o -name 'ChownFileNames*' \) -exec chown hadoop:hadoop {} +
```

There's usually no point in running `find` when you're only matching files by name (and not e.g. by date) in the current directory (without traversing subdirectories). Unless there are so many files in the current directory that this makes the command line too long, just use

```
chown hadoop:hadoop . ChownFileNames*
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the `-name` or `-iname` options in `find(1)`

Comment: And , especially, -exec option :)